# NoSql database for domain events

Tags: domain-driven-design, nosql

We are planning to implement our own custom event-store to persist our domain events, for a huge banking system (millions of events). There are many types of NoSql data-stores, and each of them seems to respond to a specific use-case : document, columns-based, key-values, etc...

We don't want to spend time managing indexes, and, in a second time, we would like to be able to feed our BI reporting system from that store.

What kind of store do you think is the most appropriate for us ?

Comment: I would not recommend MongoDB due to it does not provide ACID capability. [Vernon](https://vaughnvernon.co/?p=942) talks about it in his article and he recommends PostgreSQL as a good candidate to implement an EventStore.

Comment: @Rénald what are your needs in terms of consistency ? Scalability ? Backupability ? Customer support ? Client languages supported ? etc.

Comment: @mgonzalezbaile Vernon says nothing about PostgreSQL be a candidate for event store. He clearly uses 9.4 JSON storage capabilities and implements a document-style aggregate repository. Not a single word about saving events.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My expectation is that you should be investigating [GetEventStore](http://docs.geteventstore.com/); why roll your own when there is an open source effort with commercial support already available?

As it happens, today is the 4th anniversary of [Gabriel Schenker's series](https://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2012/06/) on creating an event store.

[Konrad Garus](http://squirrel.pl/blog/2015/09/14/achieving-consistency-in-cqrs-with-linear-event-store/) wrote about using PostgresSQL (with followup discussion on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/3l0hp1/achieving_consistency_in_cqrs_with_linear_event/)).  As did [Jeremy Miller](https://jeremydmiller.com/2014/10/22/building-an-eventstore-with-user-defined-projections-on-top-of-postgresql-and-node-js/).

[Adam Warski](http://www.warski.org/blog/2012/11/event-streaming-with-mongodb/) describes a MongoDB implementation.

[Erik Rozendaal](http://blog.zilverline.com/2012/07/30/simple-event-sourcing-redis-event-store-part-3/) writes up a Redis store.

Answer (score 1):

Full support for GES (we use it for event sourcing), plus, for curiosity, you might want to look at:

- [Marten](https://github.com/JasperFx/marten) - using PostgreSQL as document-style storage and as event store. Work in progress by already mentioned Jeremy Miller
- [Streamstone](https://github.com/yevhen/Streamstone) - event store on Azure Table Storage
- Old good [NEventStore](https://github.com/NEventStore) is "persistent agnostic" and has adapters for many popular databases

Usually what you will be looking for is:

- ACID transactions
- Subscriptions in order to be able to have projections derived directly from the event store
- Projections inside the event store for advanced stuff or to replace/complement the previous point

As per now only GES has all these features without deploying anything else.